# Python: Adwords API: How to Return a List of Available Report Types Using the API?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

On this page, there are the available report types:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports

Using an Adwords **Service**, is it possible to get a list of available report types?

**Ex**: Using the reportDefinitionService, it's possible to get report **FIELDS**:

```
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(developer_token, oauth2_client, user_agent,
                                       client_customer_id=client_customer_id)
service = adwords_client.GetService('ReportDefinitionService', api_version)
service_response = service.getReportFields('ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')

for field in service_response:
  print(field.fieldName)
```

**Returns**:

```
AccountCurrencyCode
AccountDescriptiveName
AccountTimeZoneId
ActiveViewCpm
ActiveViewCtr
ActiveViewImpressions
...
VideoViews
ViewThroughConversions
Week
Year
```

I want to do the same thing, but instead of returning available fields for a given report type, I want to return the names of report types.

Ex: desired output:

```
ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
AD_CUSTOMIZERS_FEED_ITEM_REPORT
...
URL_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
USER_AD_DISTANCE_REPORT
VIDEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
```

Which Adwords API service exists to do this?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to query for this, you would have to read the documentation and choose your report type.

If you want to automate it, I suggest you take a list of all the online reports:

[https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports][1]

and then do:

```
for report_type in report_types:
  service_response = service.getReportFields(report_type)
```

this would get you all the fields for each respective report type

Comment: Thanks for your POV. I have already done like you suggested - static list of unique report types. Since new report types appear, or possibly report types get deprecated, I am hoping to obtain this list directly from the API dynamically rather than risk having an out-dated list of static report types. I upvoted your answer but I can't select it as best because I'd like to leave it open in-case someone else knows of a way.